# SQL query to select from 3-4 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, drop-down-menu

Please find below a link to the table-structure I have set up and to the query I am running.

[Link to tables and query.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4298/2)

The present result is that only the firstnames, lastnames and "education_finished" are showing. But all the option_id's and their related lang_values still show "NULL".

The desired result:

[image: can be found here ...]

Any suggestions how to solve?

Comment: Can you show the expected result?

Comment: There isn't any related field between `phpbb_profile_fields_data` and `phpbb_profile_fields_data`

Comment: `ON d.pf_education_finished = f.field_name`

Comment: you have a join, this one: `d.pf_education_finished = f.field_name`, which does not match any data

Comment: I added the desired result of the query at the bottom of my initial question.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the query that you are using:

```
SELECT d.pf_firstname, d.pf_lastname, f.field_id, fl.option_id,
d.pf_education_finished, fl.lang_value
FROM phpbb_profile_fields_data d
LEFT JOIN phpbb_profile_fields f
ON d.pf_education_finished = f.field_name
LEFT JOIN phpbb_profile_fields_lang fl
ON f.field_id = fl.field_id
ORDER BY d.pf_lastname ASC
```

The reason why you are getting `null` value is because of this condition:

```
LEFT JOIN phpbb_profile_fields f
ON d.pf_education_finished = f.field_name
```

You are trying to `join` on pf_education_finished  (`int`) field of one table and field_name (`int`) field of another table. Also, there are no matching values (e.g. `pf_education_finished` contains numbers whereas `field_name`is 'education finished').

If you want the query to return something then you need to `join` on `field_id` and `phpbb_profile_fields` needs to have some records with matching field id, e.g.:

```
SELECT d.pf_firstname, d.pf_lastname, f.field_id, fl.option_id,
d.pf_education_finished, fl.lang_value
FROM phpbb_profile_fields_data d
LEFT JOIN phpbb_profile_fields f
ON d.pf_education_finished = f.field_id
LEFT JOIN phpbb_profile_fields_lang fl
ON f.field_id = fl.field_id
ORDER BY d.pf_lastname ASC
```

Here's the updated **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11d1e/1/0)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT d.pf_firstname, d.pf_lastname, f.field_id, fl.option_id,
d.pf_education_finished, fl.lang_value
FROM phpbb_profile_fields_lang fl 
inner JOIN phpbb_profile_fields f
ON f.field_id = fl.field_id
inner JOIN phpbb_profile_fields_data d
ON f.field_id = fl.field_id
ORDER BY d.pf_lastname ASC
```

This is the optional query if you want to display data from 3-4 tables but in this query names are repeats as per the `count of field_id` present in `phpbb_profile_fields_lang`.

The exact solution you are looking is, when you have the same primary key in all the tables from which you are retrieving the data.

Thank you.